# How to implement React-navigation with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I've just setup my Redux store in React native app. 
I moved to initialize React navigation for my project, i though that, as long as i'm using Redux to manage my app state, then the default option is that redux also is taking care of Navigation, and it should be hooked up to Redux, i opened React navigation docs, it says literally:

## "Think twice before you consider doing this, there is an incredibly good chance that you do not need to do   t his!"

So, is it a good practice to manage navigation with Redux, or just implement basic navigation the normal way (outside Redux) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Navigation manages its own state internally (using its own redux store I think...). There's no real need to connect `react-navigation` state to your own app's redux store since they expose API to do everything you might need to even without the `navigation` prop. Also it looks like they're dropping support for redux integration in the next version so beware of deprecation.

This is one of those cases where people may introduce unnecessary complexity and research into the project just to be happy about how "neat" the code runs even when it doesn't offer any real deliverable.